# Which Layout and root should I chose to mix expandable (or not) blocks in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I'm getting datas from the internet, and I need to print all of them in a layout.

Problem is **I don't know before they're displayed, the length of their text**.

I thought of doing a layout like this :

[The layout I'd need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z8PO.png)

where Title and Country blocks **shouldn't be clickable and/or expandable**, but where the **Actors block should be if the @authors text is too long**.

In fact, it should be very similar to the Google Actuality display :

[The layout I need is similar to Google Actuality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5VaZ.jpg)

I've looked at many layouts such as ExpandableViewList or RecyclerView (also TableLayout and ListView) but I can't get to find a layout which would fulfill my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display it in a `ExpandableListView` with a custom adapter that extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

Your custom adapter should look something like this.

```
class Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    static class Elem {
        String title;
        String desc;
        boolean canExpand;
    }

    private List<Elem> mData;

    public void setData(List<Elem> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
       return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) { return mData.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Elem e = (Elem)getGroup(groupPosition);
        return e.desc;
    } 

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       Elem e = mData.get(groupPosition);
       if (!e.canExpand) return 0;

       // check if either e.title OR e.desc is long enough
       // to expand
       if (is_long_enough( ...)) 
           return 1;
       return 0;
    }

    // then override the getGroupView and getChildView methods to return your views
}
```

---

when you declare your `ExpandableListView` in your layout, set its groupIndicator to null

```
            <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/list_id"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Comment: Thanks for implementing the "isExpandable" trick. That was the problem I had in finding the layout I needed.
I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a RecyclerView of items, containing a LinearLayout (it's faster to inflate, but you can use other ones), where you can store 3 CardViews, each of them containing a TextView. First and second CardViews should contain TextViews for Title and Country, but the third CardView should also have OnClick event, so you'll be able to change CardView's height (aka expand it and shrink again), if its TextView text size is bigger, than a constant threshold value.

Comment: I thought of doing it but it was going to be very complicated for what I wanted to do. Still, I think you can get to a better rendering and UI with CardViews !